# Odoo 10 - Email notifications when Sales Order or Invoices are created

Tags: python, xml, odoo-10, odoo

When a sales order is created from User A which has User B as account manager, the following email is sent:

```
Dear User B,
You have been assigned to the sales order SO-0058.
<View sales order>
Powered by Odoo.
```

Similar email is sent when an invoice is created.

Where this template can be modified?
Is there any way to disable this internal notifications globaly?

Comment: Did you find the solution ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find that notification in the module `mail`, folder `views`, file `mail_templates.xml`.

The XML ID of the template you're looking for is `message_user_assigned`.

In the same module, folder `models`, file `mail_thread.py`, there's the action of sending that notification:

```
@api.multi
def _message_auto_subscribe_notify(self, partner_ids):
    """ Notify newly subscribed followers of the last posted message.
        :param partner_ids : the list of partner to add as needaction partner of the last message
                                (This excludes the current partner)
    """
    if not partner_ids:
        return

    if self.env.context.get('mail_auto_subscribe_no_notify'):
        return

    # send the email only to the current record and not all the ids matching active_domain !
    # by default, send_mail for mass_mail use the active_domain instead of active_ids.
    if 'active_domain' in self.env.context:
        ctx = dict(self.env.context)
        ctx.pop('active_domain')
        self = self.with_context(ctx)

    for record in self:
        record.message_post_with_view(
            'mail.message_user_assigned',
            composition_mode='mass_mail',
            partner_ids=[(4, pid) for pid in partner_ids],
            auto_delete=True,
            auto_delete_message=True,
            parent_id=False, # override accidental context defaults
            subtype_id=self.env.ref('mail.mt_note').id)
```

And this action is performed in your cases because `sale.order` and `account.invoice` models inherit from `mail.thread`:

```
class AccountInvoice(models.Model):
    _name = "account.invoice"
    _inherit = ['mail.thread']
    _description = "Invoice"
    _order = "date_invoice desc, number desc, id desc"
```

I don't recommend you to remove that `_inherit`. I think it'd be better to overwrite `_message_auto_subscribe_notify` method to check the active model and do nothing if this is `sale.order` or `account.invoice`.

Comment: I just want to say that three years after this post I needed to do this again and confirm that this works. @forvas solution is comprehensive and as far as I know it is the only way to disable those annoying notifications (I am still wondering who on Earth thought it is a good idea to send internal notifications from an ERP to customers).

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to develop anything. This is configuration inside Odoo for users.

`Settings -> Technical -> Subtypes`

Regards

Comment: Sorry the subject of the question is different of the question. 
- You can configure: "Email notifications when Sales Order or Invoices are created"
- You can't configure: when a saler order or invoice is assigned to a sales person.

Comment: rafadoo please [edit] your posts instead of adding information in comments. Especially if you are not satisfied anymore and need to change something.